# Data Binding won't update after deserialize with JSon.NET (Windows Phone)

Tags: json, list, user-interface, serialization, observablecollection

I'm fairly new to Windows Phone 8 and Data binding, and have run across a problem getting a LongListSelector bound to an ObservableCollection to update after I have deserialized it from a file using JSon.NET. It works fine otherwise.

My basic test is:

- I create my list, add/change entries (via buttons in UI). List updates properly in UI.
- I serialize this to disk.
- I reload the same file into my list. The data does load properly.
- The UI now will no longer update if I change an entry, etc.

I can only get this to work as follows:

- Deserialize into a temporary list
- Clear my original list
- Manually copy over all the items in a loop from the temp list (see LoadData() below)

My data consists of a single string, and my list is an ObservableCollection as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      private string _name;
      [DataMember]
      public string name
      {
          get { return _name;}
          set
          {
              _name = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
          }
      }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string strPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
    }

    public Item(string n)
    {
      name = n;
    }
    public Item() { }
}

public class MyList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; set; }

    public MyList()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
}
```

In the calling code, I do the following:

```
public MyList theList;
public ListPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theList = new MyList();
    LoadData();

    this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = theList;
}
```

My "LoadData" method, the way I expected it to work, but causes UI to no longer update:

```
private async void LoadData()
{
    await theList.LoadJsonAsync("myfile.store");
}
```

And finally, the only way I could get LoadData to actually work:

```
private async void LoadData()
{
    MyList tempList = new MyList();
    await tempList.LoadJsonAsync("myfile.store");
    theList.items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in tempList.items)
    {
         theList.items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

For reference, I load the file in LoadDataAsync() as:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file)) 
{
   string json = r.ReadToEnd();
   items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(json);
}
```

And the relevant part of my XAML is:

```
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

The way I manually have to copy items in the working version of my LoadData() feels like it should be wrong.  Basically, it is as if the list item reference has changed after deserializing.  I have read about a similar issue here [Serializing Observable Collection](http://kentb.blogspot.ca/2007/11/serializing-observablecollection.html) but it is from 2007 and have read elsewhere this should no longer be a problem.

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

**UPDATE**

I tried just setting the ItemSource on the list again:

```
LLS.ItemsSource = theList.items; (LLS is the name of the LongListSelector)
```

instead of copying the list over in my LoadData(), and it seems to work.  But if someone can confirm that this is intended behaviour, that would be great.  I would really like to understand the "why" about this.